# Three.js move object to point along some line & lookAt

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, linear-algebra

I have a cuboid (THREE.CubeGeometry 1x1x10 for example). Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Given some point, I want to place the cuboid some distance away from the origin, but along the line formed by the origin and said point
2. Rotate the cuboid so it faces the origin

[image]

I'm tried using

```
obj.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

but that rotates the object in such a way that its side faces the origin, instead of its end.

As for the first step (finding a point along that line that is N units away from the origin), I don't even know where to start. What I did was normalize the vec with the point, which [I think] gets me, essentially, a line of length 1, from (0, 0, 0) pointing towards the point. To move that point to where I want (N distance from the origin), I can scale that vector accordingly. Not sure if that makes sense...

---

**Edit**

In answer to one of the comments saying how obj.lookAt() *should* work, here's what I'm getting, and what I'd like to have it do instead:

How the cuboid is being drawn after position is set to some point, then lookAt() invoked
[image]

Note that the side of the object is looking at the origin (not what I want)
[image]

What I'd like to do is have the object look at that point from its end (I guess I'm one rotation away from that, but that's one rotation I'm not sure how to calculate)
[image]

Comment: Create a ray in the direction of your target point, get the point on ray by the distance you want. I'm not using three.js but i guess it has a ray object, the direction of your ray is either point - origin or the reverse.

Comment: An object is by default looking up its local positive z-axis. When you call `object.lookAt( scene.position )`, the object's local z-axis will point toward the origin. If your cuboid is 1x1x10, it should do what you want.

Comment: Is the z-dimension the long side of the cube?

Comment: @WestLangley Ah! Of course. Thanks for pointing that out. Problem was that I was declaring the cuboid as 1x10x1 instead of 1x1x10 (wrong order). Works like a charm indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `object.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 )`, the object's local z-axis will point toward the origin.

So, if your cuboid is 1x1x10, with the long side parallel to the z-axis, you should get exactly the result you want.

three.js r.97

Comment: What if the long side is perpendicular to the z-axis? :/

Comment: @ManPersonson In that case, rotate the geometry (not the mesh) so it is oriented along the z-axis. For example, `geometry.rotateY( Math.PI / 2 );`